# Sending string list from Android to vb.net

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net, wcf, ksoap2

Stuck in this since 2 days now. I am trying to send complex data to vb.net WCF service. 
This is the service request:

```
class saveLoadParts extends AsyncTask<List<String>, String, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(List<String>... params) {

    List<String> checkList = new ArrayList<String>();
    checkList = oldList;
    SoapObject request  = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME4);
    SoapObject soapLogs  = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "checkList");
    for (String i : checkList){
        soapLogs.addProperty("ItemList", i);
    }

    request.addSoapObject(soapLogs );

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        transport.call(GETUSER_SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME4, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        finalResult = response.toString();

    }catch (SoapFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return finalResult;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (!result.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(OrderDetailView.this, "List Stored",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}}
```

And this is my VB.net code

```
Public Class ItemList
     Public abc As String
End Class

Function SaveLoadParts(ByVal checkList As ItemList()) As String Implements IService1.SaveLoadParts
    Dim a As String = checkList(0).abc.ToString()
    Return a
End Function
```

I have tried almost everything I can possibly find on Internet, It always give me an error

```
 Now I am getting this.
```

SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:DeserializationFailed' faultstring: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:checkList. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 361. Element 'http...' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http...'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'checkList' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

Please help!!

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to follow the error message's suggestion and enable including exceptions in faults. You'll be flying blind until you do that.

Comment: Thanks @vcsjones I follow the error and now I am getting this as an error.